Sonar Query:sonarqube-10.5.1.90531
I am using java 17 and maven Apache Maven 3.8.6 (84538c9988a25aec085021c365c560670ad80f63) and sonarqube-10.5.1.90531 ,getting below error .
please help .
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.11.0.3922:sonar (default-cli) on project SpringBootTutorial: Not authorized. Please check the user token in the property 'sonar.token' or the credentials in the properties 'sonar.login' and 'sonar.password'.

You must include these properties in your pom.xml. You can log in using either a token or credentials. Choose one method.
I have created a profile:
<profile>
    <id>sonar</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <!-- Project -->
        <sonar.branch>developer</sonar.branch>
        <!-- Sonar server -->
        <sonar.host.url>http://server_url:9000/</sonar.host.url>
        <sonar.projectKey>your_sonar_project_key</sonar.projectKey>
        
        <!-- Login using token -->
        <sonar.login>your_sonarqube_token</sonar.login>
    
        <!-- Login using credentials -->
        <sonar.login>your_sonar_login</sonar.login>
        <sonar.password>your_sonar_password</sonar.password>

    </properties>
</profile>


